# Better way to default Rails form instead of using ternary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some code like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= params[:first_name] ? params[:first_name] : 'John' %>>
```

Obviously this is not ideal as it repeats params[:first_name] twice. Is there a better way to have a form default to param, but if there is no param value for it use a default value?

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
params[:first_name] || 'John'
```

Comment: or `||=`, for assignment, too

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you aren't using [Rails' form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), but I suggest you start using them. You can use `:value => 'John'` to set the default value of a `text_field` to `"John"`:

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :attribute_name, :value => 'John' %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If for some reason it's not possible to use the form helpers then you should go with shioyama's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||=` operator in such situations as below -

```
a = "Rafa"
a.empty? ? "Nadal" : a # => "Rafa"
a ||= "Nadal" # => "Rafa"
```

If your variable is undefined and you use ternary, NameError exception will be raised

```
b ? "Rafa" : b # => NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
```

However `||=` operator will initialise it to "Nadal"

```
b ||= "Nadal" # => "Nadal"
```

Basically `b ||= "Nadal"` evaluates to `b = b || "Nadal"` i.e. if `b` already exists in the current scope use its value whatever it may be, else initialise it to "Nadal".

Comment: It will not evaluate to a `NameError` as long as `params` is defined, which it is by default.

Comment: I am talking in general context and not w.r.t. `params`. If a variable is undefined you get `NameError`. And Brad in his example `{a: 1, b: 2}[:c]` has used symbol which evaluates to `nil` because key `:c` doesn't exist. However if you instead try `{a: 1, b: 2}[c] || 3` there will be `NameError` because variable `c` is undefined

Comment: His question is about `params` so your remark "will always evaluate to either `true` or `NameError`" is incorrect. I suggest you edit your answer.